# PowerQuery Count calculated rows of big table (Performance Issue)

Tags: performance, count, powerquery

I'm having a table looking like this

| Record | Old.AttributeA | New.AttributeA | AttributeA_IsDifferent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | A | A | false |
| 0002 | B | C | true |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 5353 | A | X | false |

The is different column is calculated by doing an equality check on the old and new value.

```
 Table.AddColumn(source, "AttributeA_IsDifferent", each [Old.AttributeA] <> [New.AttributeA], type logical))
```

Now I'd like to have an additional pivot table based on the table above that looks like this:

| Record | Column | Differences Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | AttributeA | 3 |
| 002 | AttributeB | 5 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 135 | AttributeZZ | 12 |

For that I currently doing a count of row on the table:

```
= Table.AddColumn(source, "DifferencesCount", each  Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(ReportTable, (x)=> Record.Field(x, GetColumnName_IsDifferent2([Column])) = true)))
```

The *GetColumnName_IsDifferent2([Column])* gets the correct column name based on the ColumnName in the "Column" column.

Problem is that this count is freaking slow. It takes about 1 second per attribute. Approx. 2 Minutes for the whole pivot table.
Is there any room for improving the duration?

Answer (score 0):

You didnt accept or comment on any answers in your other question [PowerQuery: Adding multiple columns with calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74351855/powerquery-adding-multiple-columns-with-calculation) . What is the motivation for anyone to answer this one?

That said, lets give it one more go. Try an unpivot followed by a group

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Record"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each Text.Contains([Attribute], "IsDifferent")),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Filtered Rows","_IsDifferent","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Attribute"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{{"Value", type number}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type1", {"Record", "Attribute"}, {{"Differences Count", each List.Sum([Value]), type nullable number}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]